# Conflicting constraints in Airflow constraint file

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

For setting up AWS MWAA with snowflake, as per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-dependencies.html), I created a requirements.txt file with following content:

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.2/constraints-3.7.txt"
apache-airflow[snowflake]
```

This worked successfully. Next I wanted to add dbt to my eco-system and updated my constraint file to:

```
--constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.2/constraints-3.7.txt"
apache-airflow[snowflake]
dbt-core==1.1.1
dbt-snowflake==1.1.0
```

Now this is where things start breaking. I get the following error when I build this-

```
ERROR: Cannot install snowflake-connector-python[secure-local-storage]==2.7.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
snowflake-connector-python[secure-local-storage] 2.7.0 depends on keyring!=16.1.0 and <22.0.0; extra == "secure-local-storage"
The user requested (constraint) keyring==23.2.1
```

This seems really weird since both versions: `snowflake-connector-python 2.7.0` and `keyring==23.2.1` are enforced in the airflow constraint file itself: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.2/constraints-3.7.txt

It is highly unlikely that airflow constraint file is incorrect. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I guess there are some inconsistencies and version conflicts. What I ended up doing is copying all libraries from constraints.txt to requirements.txt, removing unused libraries and run `./mwaa-local-env test-requirements` to check for inconsistencies.
Then I manually changed versions of all version conflicts.